# Table - aligning negative numbers

Tags: tables

I have created the following table, however the negative numbers are not aligned. Do you have any hacks on how I can solve this problem?

```
    \documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=12mm, bottom=20mm}

    \begin{table}[htbp!]
    \caption{Koeffizienten der CFA}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
    {\scriptsize
        \begin{tabular}{@{} lccccc @{} } \toprule
            & {B} & {SE} & {$z$} & {$p$} & {$\beta$} \\\midrule
            {Variablen}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            \emph{ Extraversion} &  &  & && \\      
            Item 1 & $ 1.000$&& && $0.72$\\
            Item 6 & $-0.64$&$0.04$& $-14.88$&$ < .001$& $-0.54$\\
            Item 11 & $ 1.15$&$0.06$& $18.94$& $< .001$ & $0.77$\\
            Item 16 & $ -0.80$&$0.05$& $-17.47$&$ < .001$& $-0.65$\\
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Verträglichkeit} &  &  & && \\
            Item 2 & $ 1.000$&& && $0.38$\\
            Item 7 & $-0.61$&$0.11$& $-5.56$&$ < .001$& $-0.23$\\
            Item 12 & $ 2.05$&$0.22$& $9.41$&$ < .001$& $0.73$\\
            Item 17 & $ 1.97$&$0.21$& $9.40$&$ < .001$& $0.73$\\
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Gewissenhaftigkeit} &  &  & && \\        
            Item 3 & $ 1.000$&& && $0.72$\\
            Item 8 & $-0.83$&$0.07$& $-12.45$&$ < .001$& $-0.48$\\
            Item 13 & $ 1.01$&$0.67$& $15.65$& $< .001$ & $0.70$\\
            Item 18 & $ 1.97$&$0.21$& $9.40$&$ < .001$& $0.73$\\
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Neurotizismus} &  &  & && \\     
            Item 4 & $ 1.000$&& && $0.63$\\
            Item 9 & $-0.72$&$0.06$& $-11.68$&$ < .001$& $-0.48$\\
            Item 14 & $ 1.03$&$0.07$& $13.93$& $< .001$ & $0.64$\\
            Item 19 & $ 1.00$&$0.07$& $14.05$&$ < .001$& $0.67$\\   
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Offenheit} &  &  & && \\     
            Item 5 & $ 1.000$&& && $0.40$\\
            Item 10 & $1.09$&$0.12$& $8.83$&$ < .001$& $0.40$\\
            Item 15 & $ 1.30$&$0.13$& $9.79$& $< .001$ & $0.48$\\
            Item 20 & $ 2.34$&$0.21$& $11.33$&$ < .001$& $0.81$\\   
            Item 21 & $ -2.35$&$0.21$& $-11.32$&$ < .001$& $-0.73$\\    
            \bottomrule  
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

2. Also, do you know how I can make the table wider without changing the vertical spacing?

Right now, my table looks like this: 
[image: Table right now]

Thank you all very much for your help!

Kind regards, 
Milkovena

Comment: Take a look at the `S` type column from `siunitx`.

Comment: Why would you want to make your table wider than it currently is? Excessive white space will not improve the readability.

Comment: @leandriis that it not entirely true. Cramped data can benefit from more space. I agree that here is ot not really that relevant.

Comment: Please complete your example into something compilable.

Comment: @daleif: I totally agree, however I wouldn't necesarily describe the current table as to contain "cramped data".

Comment: @leandriis no it only needs centering

Answer (score 2):

Here are two versions of your table using `siunitx` to align the numbers in the table cells with respect to the decimal marker:

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=12mm, bottom=20mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp!]
    \caption{Koeffizienten der CFA}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l
                            S[table-format=-1.4]
                            S[table-format=1.2]
                            S[table-format=-2.2]
                            S[table-format=<.4, add-integer-zero=false]
                            S[table-format=-1.2] @{} } \toprule
            & {B} & {SE} & { $z$ } & {$p$} & {$\beta$} \\\midrule
            {Variablen}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            \emph{ Extraversion} &  &  & && \\      
            Item 1 &   1.000 && &&  0.72 \\
            Item 6 &  -0.64 & 0.04 &  -14.88 &  < .001 & -0.54\\
            Item 11 &   1.15 & 0.06 &  18.94 &  < .001  & 0.77\\
            Item 16 &   -0.80 & 0.05 &  -17.47 &  < .001 & -0.65\\
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Verträglichkeit} &  &  & && \\
            Item 2 &   1.000 && &&  0.38 \\
            Item 7 &  -0.61 & 0.11 &  -5.56 &  < .001 &  -0.23 \\
            Item 12 &   2.05 & 0.22 &  9.41 &  < .001 &  0.73 \\
            Item 17 &   1.97 & 0.21 &  9.40 &  < .001 &  0.73 \\
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Gewissenhaftigkeit} &  &  & && \\        
            Item 3 &   1.000 && &&  0.72 \\
            Item 8 &  -0.83 & 0.07 &  -12.45 &  < .001 &  -0.48 \\
            Item 13 &   1.01 & 0.67 &  15.65 &  < .001  &  0.70 \\
            Item 18 &   1.97 & 0.21 &  9.40 &  < .001 &  0.73 \\
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Neurotizismus} &  &  & && \\     
            Item 4 &   1.000 && &&  0.63 \\
            Item 9 &  -0.72 & 0.06 &  -11.68 &  < .001 &  -0.48 \\
            Item 14 &   1.03 & 0.07 &  13.93 &  < .001  &  0.64 \\
            Item 19 &   1.00 & 0.07 &  14.05 &  < .001 &  0.67 \\   
            &&&&&\\
            \emph{ Offenheit} &  &  & && \\     
            Item 5 &   1.000 && &&  0.40 \\
            Item 10 &  1.09 & 0.12 &  8.83 &  < .001 &  0.40 \\
            Item 15 &   1.30 & 0.13 &  9.79 &  < .001  &  0.48 \\
            Item 20 &   2.34 & 0.21 &  11.33 &  < .001 &  0.81 \\   
            Item 21 &   -2.35 & 0.21 &  -11.32 &  < .001 &  -0.73 \\    
            \bottomrule  
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}



    \begin{table}[htbp!]
    \caption{Koeffizienten der CFA}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{    l
                            S[table-format=-1.4]
                            S[table-format=1.2]
                            S[table-format=-2.2]
                            S[table-format=<.4, add-integer-zero=false]
                            S[table-format=-1.2] @{} } \toprule
            Variablen & {B} & {SE} & { $z$ } & {$p$} & {$\beta$} \\\midrule
            \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\emph{Extraversion}} \\      
            Item 1 &   1.000 && &&  0.72 \\
            Item 6 &  -0.64 & 0.04 &  -14.88 &  < .001 & -0.54\\
            Item 11 &   1.15 & 0.06 &  18.94 &  < .001  & 0.77\\
            Item 16 &   -0.80 & 0.05 &  -17.47 &  < .001 & -0.65\\
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\emph{Verträglichkeit}} \\
            Item 2 &   1.000 && &&  0.38 \\
            Item 7 &  -0.61 & 0.11 &  -5.56 &  < .001 &  -0.23 \\
            Item 12 &   2.05 & 0.22 &  9.41 &  < .001 &  0.73 \\
            Item 17 &   1.97 & 0.21 &  9.40 &  < .001 &  0.73 \\
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\emph{Gewissenhaftigkeit}} \\        
            Item 3 &   1.000 && &&  0.72 \\
            Item 8 &  -0.83 & 0.07 &  -12.45 &  < .001 &  -0.48 \\
            Item 13 &   1.01 & 0.67 &  15.65 &  < .001  &  0.70 \\
            Item 18 &   1.97 & 0.21 &  9.40 &  < .001 &  0.73 \\
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\emph{Neurotizismus}} \\     
            Item 4 &   1.000 && &&  0.63 \\
            Item 9 &  -0.72 & 0.06 &  -11.68 &  < .001 &  -0.48 \\
            Item 14 &   1.03 & 0.07 &  13.93 &  < .001  &  0.64 \\
            Item 19 &   1.00 & 0.07 &  14.05 &  < .001 &  0.67 \\   
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\emph{Offenheit}} \\     
            Item 5 &   1.000 && &&  0.40 \\
            Item 10 &  1.09 & 0.12 &  8.83 &  < .001 &  0.40 \\
            Item 15 &   1.30 & 0.13 &  9.79 &  < .001  &  0.48 \\
            Item 20 &   2.34 & 0.21 &  11.33 &  < .001 &  0.81 \\   
            Item 21 &   -2.35 & 0.21 &  -11.32 &  < .001 &  -0.73 \\    
            \bottomrule  
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```